# Don't hold your breath

Tags: traduction, anglais, locutions

Ayant constaté la demande pour des équivalents de locutions anglaises ces derniers jours (par exemple, [*damn it*](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/27160/9870) ou [*flog a dead horse*](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/51309/9870)), j'ai eu l'idée de  poser une question sur l'une d'entre elles.
Y-a-t-il une expression française pour ***don't hold your breath*** - dans le sens qu'il ne faut pas attendre que quelque chose arrive (ou que ça arrive très vite) ?

Comment: Ces derniers jours, c'est vite dit. La question sur *damn it* a cinq ans :-)

Comment: @jlliagre y-a-t-il déjà une question-wiki sur les expressions idiomatiques?

Comment: Je dirais "fonce" ou "agis sans attendre" dans le sens littéral "ne retiens pas ton souffle"... Mais c'est sans doute erroné. 
Tout dépend toujours du contexte. Bien à vous.

Comment: Ceci pourrait être utile : https://www.wordreference.com/enfr/Don't%20hold%20your%20breath

Answer (score 1):

Une possibilité est :

> *Ce n'est pas pour demain.*

(dans le sens *it is not going to happen anytime soon*)

Comment: Proche et plus courant : *C'est pas demain la veille*.

Comment: Très courant aussi : Ne compte pas là-dessus !